# JSON Data - Parsed Or 'Eval'ed

Tags: javascript, security, json

From a security perspective, I can see simply doing an 'eval' on incoming JSON data as a critical mistake. If you got data like below you'd have some problems.

```
{ someData:((function() { 
    alert("i'm in ur code hackin' ur page"); 
})()) }
```

I wondered what do most popular Javascript libraries do? Is it a manual parse or simply an eval?

**[Edit]**

I'm not asking if *I* should eval/parse - I was asking what methods some of the popular Javascript libraries used (jQuery, Prototype, etc...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what the [official JavaScript parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) does:

```
// In the second stage, we run the text against regular expressions that look
// for non-JSON patterns. We are especially concerned with '()' and 'new'
// because they can cause invocation, and '=' because it can cause mutation.
// But just to be safe, we want to reject all unexpected forms.

// We split the second stage into 4 regexp operations in order to work around
// crippling inefficiencies in IE's and Safari's regexp engines. First we
// replace the JSON backslash pairs with '@' (a non-JSON character). Second, we
// replace all simple value tokens with ']' characters. Third, we delete all
// open brackets that follow a colon or comma or that begin the text. Finally,
// we look to see that the remaining characters are only whitespace or ']' or
// ',' or ':' or '{' or '}'. If that is so, then the text is safe for eval.

if (/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.
    test(text.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, '@').
    replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, ']').
    replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, ''))) {

// In the third stage we use the eval function to compile the text into a
// JavaScript structure. The '{' operator is subject to a syntactic ambiguity
// in JavaScript: it can begin a block or an object literal. We wrap the text
// in parens to eliminate the ambiguity.

    j = eval('(' + text + ')');

    ...
```

With the exception of the built-in [JSON parsing support](http://caniuse.com/json) that is in modern browsers, this is what all (library-based) secure JSON parsers do (ie, a regex test before `eval`).

**Secure libraries** (in addition to the official json2 implementation)

Prototype's [`isJSON`](http://www.prototypejs.org/assets/2009/6/16/prototype.js) function.

Mootools' [`JSON.decode`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/JSON#JSON:decode) function (again, via a [regex test before `eval`](http://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Utilities/JSON.js#L42)).

**Unsecure libraries**:

dojo's [`fromJson`](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dojo.fromJson) does *not* provide secure `eval`ing. [Here is their entire implementation (minus comments)](http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/tags/release-1.3.2/dojo/_base/json.js):

```
dojo.fromJson = function(json) {
    return eval("(" + json + ")");
}
```

jQuery does not provide secure JSON `eval`'ing, but see the official plugin's [`secureEvalJSON`](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/source/browse/trunk/jquery.json.js) function (line 143).

Comment: that's one heck of a regular expression

Comment: Actually, some JSON parsers have a safemode that skips the regex. This mode is faster, but also less safe.

Comment: @Henrik: if it's less safe, why do you call it "safemode"? ;)

Comment: Because it assumes that the input is already safe. (When it comes from a server you control, this sounds reasonable.)

Answer (score 1):

You should absolutely parse it! JSON is just a subset of JavaScript. But `eval` would evaluate any JavaScript code and not that specific subset like a JSON parser would.

Answer (score 0):

use [evalJSON()](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/evalJSON) instead?
As far as I know this basically calls eval() after some sanitation checks.

Answer (score 0):

From http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/ :

> A fast and secure JSON parser in
>   JavaScript?
>
> This JSON parser does not attempt to
>   validate the JSON, so may return a
>   result given a syntactically invalid
>   input, but does not use eval so is
>   deterministic and is guaranteed not to
>   modify any object other than its
>   return value.
>
> There are a number of JSON parsers in
>   JavaScript? at json.org. This
>   implementation should be used whenever
>   security is a concern (when JSON may
>   come from an untrusted source), speed
>   is a concern, and erroring on
>   malformed JSON is not a concern.
>
> This implementation
>
> - Pros  Fast, secure
> - Cons  Not validating
>
> json_parse.js
>
> - Pros  Validating, secure
> - Cons  Slow
>
> json2.js
>
> - Pros  Fast, some validation
> - Cons  Potentially insecure
>
> json2.js is very fast, but potentially
>   insecure since it calls eval to parse
>   JSON data, so an attacker might be
>   able to supply strange JS that looks
>   like JSON, but that executes arbitrary
>   javascript.
>
> If you do have to use json2.js with
>   untrusted data, make sure you keep
>   your version of json2.js up to date so
>   that you get patches as they're
>   released.