# Use JSON parse instead of eval

Tags: javascript, json

I have this string that I generate in JAVA and pass to javascript to be parsed.

This works:

```
var childString = '[{title: "Item 1"},{title: "Folder 2", isFolder: true,children: [{title: "Sub-item 2.1"},{title: "Sub-item 2.2"}]},{title: "Item 3"}]';
var childArray = eval(childString);
```

But I've read everywhere that `eval == evil` so i'm looking into the JSON way of parsing.
I tried using `JSON.parse(childString)`, but I got an error.

How could I do this the JSON way?

Thanks!

Comment: _'but I got an error.'_ What was the error?

Comment: I'm *sure* you mean `eval === evil`. :)

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ is your friend.

Comment: @Felix: :) thats pretty cool. invalid json right?

Comment: @naveen: Yep, the keys have to be in double quotes. Don't understand your second comment though.

Comment: @Felix: was mentioning that OP was using an arraqy of objects and not valid JSON

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON Data - Parsed Or 'Eval'ed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143417/json-data-parsed-or-evaled)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't parse it using JSON.parse because your json string is invalid. It needs to be as follows:

```
var childString = '[{"title": "Item 1"},{"title": "Folder 2", "isFolder": true,"children": [{"title": "Sub-item 2.1"},{"title": "Sub-item 2.2"}]},{"title": "Item 3"}]';
```

[See here.](http://jsfiddle.net/YgnLa/2/)

Answer (score 7):

Your data is valid JavaScript (which is why `eval` works) but it is not valid JSON. For example you need to surround the name of your properties with quotes.

E.g.

```
'[{"title": "Item 1"} ...
```

You can find the JSON spec [here](http://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your browser, you may need to define the `JSON` object yourself. You can download the code for it from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON isn't well formed. You need double quotes on both the *keys* and the *values*.

```
'{"foo":"bar"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Include [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) in your HTML output using a `script` tag, and you can then use `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SbHH4/):

```
var childArray = JSON.parse(childString.replace(/([{, ])([a-zA-Z0-9]+):/g, '$1"$2":'));
```

will work, but I might still try to get valid JSON instead.

Answer (score 1):

Note: The double quotes are imperative.
THIS WOULD NOT WORK:

```
var childString = "[{'title': 'Item 1'},{'title': 'Folder 2', 'isFolder': true,'children': [{'title': 'Sub-item 2.1'},{'title': 'Sub-item 2.2'}]},{'title': 'Item 3'}]";
```

Comment: The double quotes needed to be passed within the string.  So you need to single quote the object '[ ..... ]'  and have the double quotes internally '[ ""...""..."" ]'.